# Calculate + IF in DAX for Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a table (PIB) with 3 fields: Name, Filter and Value
I have this Measure to deploy Data, and it works:

```
 Data = CALCULATE(
                SUM('PIB'[Value]),    
                'PIB'[Filter] IN { "Dato base" }
                )
```

I want to add an IF (or something similar) to multiply Value by -1 when column Name equals to "Companies". I have tried this, and doesn`t work:

```
Data = CALCULATE(
                IF('PIB'[Name]=Companies; SUM('PIB'[Value])*-1;SUM('PIB'[Value])),    
                'PIB'[Filter] IN { " Dato base" }
                )
```

Anybody knows how can I do it? This way or any other
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Data = 
VAR x = 
CALCULATE(
        SUM('PIB'[Value]),    
        'PIB'[Filter] IN { "Dato base" }
        )
RETURN 
IF(MAX(PIB[Name]) = "Companies", x*-1, x)
```